# Are AWS Console Permissions separate from AWS CLI Permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I have permissions to create lambda functions, as well as RDS instances. I am able to use these tools via the AWS console without issue. However, each of the following commands fail:

```
$ aws lambda list-functions

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ListFunctions 
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<IAM ID>:user/<username> is not 
authorized to perform: lambda:ListFunctions on resource: * with an explicit deny
```

```
$ aws rds describe-db-instances

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeDBInstances 
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<IAM ID>:user/<username> is not 
authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances with an explicit deny
```

Are there separate permissions that are needed for CLI access?

Comment: Does your AWS user by chance require MFA?

Comment: When you select any RDS DB in the console, are you able to see all the details?

Comment: My account requires MFA, which I have enabled. I am able to see all the details about RDS and lambda in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michael-sqlbot helped me realize that I was not using MFA on the CLI, which is what caused the error. I followed the instructions listed on [Using Temporary Security Credentials to Request Access to AWS Resources - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) to solve my problem.